# Png over jpeg (water mark effect) bad quality?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, png, jpeg

Hi i have two Writablebitmap , one from jpg and another from png and use this method to mix color in a loop:

```
private static Color Mix(Color from, Color to, float percent)
{
    float amountFrom = 1.0f - percent;
    return Color.FromArgb(
        (byte)(from.A * amountFrom + to.A * percent),
        (byte)(from.R * amountFrom + to.R * percent),
        (byte)(from.G * amountFrom + to.G * percent),
        (byte)(from.B * amountFrom + to.B * percent));
}
```

My problem is in alpha channel, my watermark effect result is bad (quality)!

[image: Result]

This is the original png.

[image: Original Pgn]

This is the original jpg.

[image: Original Jpg]

Any Help?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "bad quality" of your watermark that you'd like to avoid?

Comment: Your png is anti-aliased, it will only look good on a white background.  Recompressing it to jpeg was the neck-shot.  No simple solution for this, the watermark can't use anti-aliasing.

Comment: I'm thinking this has to do with having a jpg source.  The lossy compression on a jpeg utilizes psycho-visual models to make the compression artifacts less visible.  Overlaying an image on top of this compressed image will blow this model out of whack.  The best way to solve this is use an losslessly compressed image source for both your watermark and your source image.

Comment: @Hans: You can theoretically anti-alias an image irrespective of background source by utilizing variable opacity (when creating the image).  Whether that was done with this image or not is a separate question.  I tried saving it and opening in mspaint.  It has a black background, but there is a white hilight, so this problem might be applicable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you probably don't want the result to take on any alpha from the watermark, you want it to retain 100% of the opacity of the JPEG. Instead of setting the new alpha to `from.A * amountFrom + to.A * percent`, just use `from.A`.

**Edit:** In addition you want the `percent` to be adjusted according to the alpha of the PNG. Here's your sample, updated:

```
private static Color Mix(Color from, Color to, float percent) 
{
    float amountTo = percent * to.A / 255.0;
    float amountFrom = 1.0f - amountTo; 
    return Color.FromArgb( 
        from.A, 
        (byte)(from.R * amountFrom + to.R * amountTo), 
        (byte)(from.G * amountFrom + to.G * amountTo), 
        (byte)(from.B * amountFrom + to.B * amountTo)); 
}
```

I converted this code to Python and ran your sample images through it with 0.5 percent, here's the result:

[image]

Comment: You said it before I could. +1 on the picture if only I could rate it separately.

Comment: @Ingenu, I was wondering if anyone would notice my new avatar. I changed it last night.